# SQL Server: Datetimeoffset to timestamp (with 6 digit sec precision)

Tags: sql-server

This is my source column time format

```
2018-08-08 14:23:36.4865019 +01:00
```

And while retrieving same column expected out is only

```
2018-08-08 14:23:36.486501
```

Can you please help me with conversion/cast statement.

Answer (score 0):

use `datetime2` as a datatype

```
select cast ('2018-08-08 14:23:36.4865019 +01:00' as datetime2(6))
```

example

```
 select cast (schema.dbo.A.[X] as datetime2(6)) FROM schema.dbo.A
```

Comment: Zaynul,

I have column 'X' in a table A where data-type is datetimeoffset and while selecting column 'X' from table A, I want output should be timestamp


Column 'X' value : 2018-08-08 14:23:36.4865019 +01:00
expected output after cast/conversion for column A should be like this : 2018-08-08 14:23:36.486501

Comment: @RoshanNagpure select cast ('2018-08-08 14:23:36.4865019 +01:00' as datetime2(6));

Comment: Query :  select cast ('schema.dbo.A.[X]' as datetime2(6))
FROM 
schema.dbo.A;


Reason:
SQL Error [241] [S0001]: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @RoshanNagpure use try_cast

Comment: @RoshanNagpure do not need single quote

Comment: Zaynul,

select WorkDateTime as source_value, try_cast (WorkDateTime as datetime2(7)) as after_conversion  from  schemaname.dbo.A

It is changing milliseconds --- 2018-08-08 14:23:36.2336

Is there anything that would help ?

source_value,after_conversion
2018-08-08 14:23:36.4865019 +01:00 2018-08-08 14:23:36.2336

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190692/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-roshan-nagpure).